# Is jQuery 1.3.2 causing this not to work, or something else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-1.3.2

I know that this is supposed to work, it works fine in 1.7.2

```
//click anywhere to close dropdown
$("html").live("click", function () {
    closeDropdown();
});

//on click of ellipsis, open dropdown
$("span.PivotEllipsis").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    openDropdown();
});
```

It is the classic click outside span.PivotEllipsis to hide.  However, the problem is that the second function is not working.  The first is working fine, when you click outside, it hides.  However, when you click on the span.Pivot Ellipsis it doesn't pop up, instead I think, hard to tell though, that it runs openDropdown() and then immediately after closeDropdown()....

Anyone know what it wrong?

Comment: [Works fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/mpaYB/) in jQuery 1.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/): "it is not possible to stop propagation of live events."  You don't really need to use `.live()` as the html element exists at document.ready and isn't dynamically loaded

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I'm not sure if they mean you can't stop the propagation of an event IN a live handler, or if you can't stop an event from propagating TO a live handler... hmmm.

Comment: Yes, they mean *in* the `.live()` handler. You can still stop propagation on the handlers bound to sub Elements, an it will prevent the event from bubbling up to the document.

Answer (score 0):

What you thought is probably correct - you need to disable the first function while the dropdown menu is not open.

Comment: Why? If OP is using `stopPropagation`, the event should never reach the `.live()` handler, and therefore never invoke the `closeDropdown()` function.